How to implement image upload in TipTap editor in Vue 3
I'm using Laravel Inertia with Vue 3 and trying to implement something that will help me to upload images to the db with help of TipTap editor.
I found implementation with React: https://gist.github.com/slava-vishnyakov/16076dff1a77ddaca93c4bccd4ec4521
But I need it for Vue 3.

Could you just write an upload controller? This may be quicker than searching for a library for it.

In the example below, uploading an image as base64 works fine for me. With a few minor changes, you can upload the image to the server and have it added dynamically.
<template>
  <div>
    <editor-content :editor="editor" />
    <input 
      type="file" 
      id="file-upload-input" 
      ref="fileInput" 
      @change="onFileChange" 
      accept="image/png,image/jpg,image/jpeg,image/gif,image/webp" 
      hidden 
    />
    <button @click="triggerFileUpload">Upload Image</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref, onMounted, onBeforeUnmount } from "vue";
import { EditorContent, useEditor } from "@tiptap/vue-3";
import StarterKit from "@tiptap/starter-kit";
import Image from "@tiptap/extension-image";

export default {
  name: "TiptapImageUpload",
  components: { EditorContent },
  setup() {
    const editor = useEditor({
      extensions: [
        StarterKit,
        Image.extend({
          addOptions() {
            return {
              ...this.parent?.(),
              inline: false,
              allowBase64: true,
            };
          },
        }),
      ],
      content: "<p>Click the button below to upload an image!</p>",
    });

    const onFileChange = async (event) => {
      const file = event.target.files[0];
      if (file) {
        const reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = () => {
          const base64 = reader.result;
          editor
            .chain()
            .focus()
            .setImage({ src: base64 })
            .run();
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      }
      event.target.value = ""; // Reset the input
    };

    const triggerFileUpload = () => {
      document.getElementById("file-upload-input").click();
    };

    onMounted(() => {
      console.log("Editor mounted");
    });

    onBeforeUnmount(() => {
      editor?.destroy();
    });

    return {
      editor,
      triggerFileUpload,
      onFileChange,
    };
  },
};
</script>

<style>
/* Basic styling */
button {
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  background-color: #007bff;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #0056b3;
}
</style>

